# IIS7 301 Redirects - The correct way

Tags: windows, wordpress, redirect, iis-7, server

We have built a Wordpress site and the clients server is running Windows. I personally have never worked with a Windows server.

I am trying to get the 301 redirects to work. So far I have had no luck. We have a **web.config** file set up with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogv" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is working and the site is running as expected. But when I try adding the list of 301's in between **< rules >** tags they don't seem to work. I don't receive any errors, it just doesn't redirect when going to the old url. I have been advised by the server admin that the **Routing Module** has been installed.

My rule:

```
<rule name="301 Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/insight/$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="/services/insight/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Another:

```
<rule name="301 Redirect 2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/contact-us/$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="/contact/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Is anyone able to advise?

----- EDIT -----

I have also tried:

```
<rule name="301 Redirect 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="\/contact-us\/$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="/contact/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I have also changed the pattern to match if a slash ( / ) is at the end of the url:

```
<rule name="301 Redirect 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="\/contact-us((\/\w+)+|\/?)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="/contact/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Remove the leading / in pattern and try again.

Comment: @LexLi unfortunately this did not work either